# Wizard Form not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Wizard form is not submitting. Originally configured to give a notification when  there are no errors instead of submitting. I want the form to submit. I therefore modified original code to as below

```js
$w4finish.on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var validated = $('#w4 form').valid();
  if (validated) return true;
  this.submit();
});
```

But it is still not submitting.

Comment: Can you tell us that what error you are getting in console  ?

Comment: You are returning true if the form validates. Every code after this won't get executed, including the `this.submit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point fires `return` and further code is not executed.

```
if (validated) { return true }
```

Remove this line if not needed or change function to this one:

```
$w4finish.on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var validated = $('#w4 form').valid();
  if (validated) {
    this.submit();
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: I get this error in console Uncaught TypeError: this.submit is not a function(…)

Comment: Try change `this.submit();` to: `$(this).submit();`